# chaining proximity searches in solr

Tags: python-requests, solr

I have a snippet here which queries the index based on some proximity search like so:

```
        resp=requests.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/my_index/select', params={
        'q': f'"{q_solr}"'+'~1',  # proximity 0 ie exact match
        'wt': 'json',
        'rows': 5,
        'start': 0,
        'fl': 'id,org*,score',
        })
```

where `q_solr` is the term iam searching for. I would like to chain queries at this stage, as in do:

```
query1+query2+query3
```

using the `AND` operator. How does one include this in this line?

```
        'q': f'"{q_solr}"'+'~1',
```

How does one chain to this query? I basicaly want:

```
        'q': f'"{q_solr}"'+'~1' AND f'"{X_solr}"'+'~1' AND f'"{Y_solr}"'+'~1',
```

where `X_solr` and `Y_solr` are different terms.

It seems more like a syntax issue but Iam not able to overcome this.

Comment: `f'"{q_solr}"~1 AND "{X_solr}"~1 AND "{Y_solr}"~1'` - each `{}` surrounds the variable you want expanded inside your string to give you the end result you're looking for. Think of them as placeholders inside the string, instead of using `"string1" + "string2"` to merge strings.

Comment: yea I just got that :D if you could please post me as an answer I will accept it :)